# tree for symbolic regression early stops when unary operator is used

Tags: python, binary-tree

im working on a symbolic regression algorithm, by now i have this node

```
class Node:
    def __init__(self):
        self.left = None
        self.right = None
        self.arity = 0
        self.left_col = 0
        self.right_col = 0
        self.operator_ = 0
```

for the tree to be printed we can use this test set

```
2,4,0,7,77,2,
2,1,1,48,37,7,
-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,
-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,
2,3,2,49,58,2,
-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,
2,2,3,101,59,2,
2,1,4,62,19,5,
-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,
-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,
-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,
```

now my Program start loading a file and creating the node whit the data of the test set, then we proced to print the tree as you can see:

```
class Program:
    def __init__(self):
        self.tree = None

    def load_tree(self, p, file):
        line = file.readline()
        x = line.split(',')
        x.pop(-1)
        x = [int(i) for i in x]
        print(x)
        if (x[0] == -1):
            return None
        else:
            p.arity = x[0]
            p.left_col = x[3]
            p.right_col = x[4]
            p.operator_ = x[5]
            p.left = Node()
            p.right = Node()
            p.left = self.load_tree(p.left, file)
            p.right = self.load_tree(p.right, file)
        return p

    def load_program(self, PROGNAME):
        file = open(str(PROGNAME) + ".csv", "r")
        if self.tree == None:
            self.tree = Node()
        self.load_tree(self.tree, file)
        file.close()

    def print_tree(self, tree, ncol):
        result = ""
        operators = {0: "not", 1: "shift", 2: "+", 3: "-", 4: "*",
                     5: "/", 6: ">", 7: "<", 8: "=="}
        if tree == None:
            result += "v" + str(ncol)
        elif tree.arity == 1:
            result += operators[tree.operator_] + \
                "(" + self.print_tree(tree.left, tree.left_col) + ")"
        elif tree.arity == 2:
            result += "(" + self.print_tree(tree.left, tree.left_col) + \
                operators[tree.operator_] + \
                self.print_tree(tree.right, tree.right_col) + ")"
        return result

    def print_program(self):
        y = "y = " + self.print_tree(self.tree, 0)
        print(y)
prog = Program()

# load_program
prog.load_program(0)

# print_program
prog.print_program()
```

and the output formula will be:

```
y = ((v48<v37)+(v49+((v62/v19)+v59)))
```

but now if we use this other dataset whit an unary operator in the third(non -1) row

```
2,4,0,7,77,2,
2,1,1,48,37,7,
-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,
-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,
1,3,2,49,58,0,
-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,
2,2,3,101,59,2,
2,1,4,62,19,5,
-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,
-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,
-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,
```

the output stop been calculated at that point, here the output

```
y = ((v48<v37)+not(v49))
```

why is this happening? and how can it be solved in order to end the calculation?

thanks in advance!

edition:

i have changed the load_tree adding the if (x[0]==1): to looks like this, but i have the same output

```
def load_tree(self, p, file):
    line = file.readline()
    x = line.split(',')
    x.pop(-1)
    x = [int(i) for i in x]
    print(x)
    if (x[0] == -1):
        return None
    if (x[0] == 1):
        p.arity = x[0]
        p.left_col = x[3]
        p.operator_ = x[5]
        p.left = Node()
        p.left = self.load_tree(p.left, file)
        
    elif (x[0] == 2):
        p.arity = x[0]
        p.left_col = x[3]
        p.right_col = x[4]
        p.operator_ = x[5]
        p.left = Node()
        p.right = Node()
        p.left = self.load_tree(p.left, file)
        p.right = self.load_tree(p.right, file)
    return p
```

y = ((v48<v37)+not(v49))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code in `load_tree` ignores the arity and expects left and right subnode even for the "not" operator. The right subnode of "not" is the remaining "+" operation which in turn has a "/" operation as left subnode.

`print_tree` on the other hand ignores the right subnode of unary operations.

Comment: thanks for the answer, for the  load_tree should i put p.right = None ? or an if when x[0]==1?

Comment: @mimus You can either change the csv and insert a "-1, - 1,...“ line for the right node or put an "if x[0] == 1:..." in "load_tree" to only load a left subnode in this case.

Comment: i try to edit the code but the error, hope you can helpme im little lost

Comment: @mimus Now the tree is already complete before the line "2,2,3,101,59,2". All previous nodes already have their subnodes therefore the processing of the csv stops.

Comment: ok! looks great! the load_tree is fine now, but on the part of the print_tree,  what do you mean that ignores the right subnode of the unary operations? should i call the tree.right on the elif tree.arity == 1: ? in advance thanks

Comment: @mimus No, the behavior of "print_tree" is right. I only wanted to emphasize that the behavior of "load_tree" wasn't consistent with that.